# Unable to copy any file to external HDD

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, chkdsk

I have WD My Passport 4TB External Hard Drive. When I try to copy any file to WD HDD, it gives me error: "Cant read from the source file or disk". But I can copy any file in HDD to my laptop. Also it does not seem to be write protected:

[image]

I can copy paste from my other seagate hard drive and transcend pen drive to my laptop. So it seem to be an issue with WD hard drive and not the laptop.

I also tried running chkdsk against WD hard drive. It took forever, so I killed it. But here is the output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> chkdsk D: /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is My Passport.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
File record segment 4513C is unreadable.
File record segment 4513D is unreadable.
File record segment 4513E is unreadable.
File record segment 4513F is unreadable.
File record segment 45140 is unreadable.
File record segment 45141 is unreadable.
File record segment 45142 is unreadable.
File record segment 45143 is unreadable.
File record segment 45144 is unreadable.
File record segment 45145 is unreadable.
File record segment 45146 is unreadable.
File record segment 45147 is unreadable.
File record segment 45153 is unreadable.
File record segment 45158 is unreadable.
File record segment 45183 is unreadable.
File record segment 4519C is unreadable.
File record segment 4519D is unreadable.
File record segment 4524C is unreadable.
File record segment 4524D is unreadable.
File record segment 4524E is unreadable.
File record segment 4524F is unreadable.
Progress: 283316 of 287744 done; Stage: 98%; Total: 33%; ETA:   2:15:05
```

How can I fix this WD HDD?

PS: I am Windows 10.

**Update**

Here is the screenshot of the WD utility:
[image]

I am not able to copy from Ubuntu to HDD:

[image]

Comment: Same problem on another machine?  If so, the external drive has probably died.

Comment: You may want to copy any data you need to keep from that WD Passport drive onto another drive while it is still letting you copy from it.

Comment: To test a drive, you need a utility such as [WD Drive Utilities](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/13880). Use the S.M.A.R.T. check to get some statistics which you could edit into your question so that people can see if the drive itself is definitely failing.

Comment: drive ist kaput.

Comment: @AndrewMorton added the screenshot. Where to get statistics?

Comment: @RajS The screenshot tells me that first, copy any data you want to keep from the drive. *Then* worry about how to find out how broken it is.

Comment: The drive tests have failed - get your data out and replace the disk.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. But the drive is barely 4 years old. My older Segate 1TB drive is still working perfectly! So am guessing whats wrong I might have done. Also, this drive is almost  3TB full. To backup this, I will need to buy new 4TB one, which is not that cheap now .

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes will do that. Given that I have test this hard drive on two Windows and one Ubuntu machine, am at least 90% sure that HDD is screwed. But am curious why all of them say source disk is not readable. Windows say "Cant read from the source file or disk". Ubuntu says "Error opening file". And none say Destination disk is unreadable! Added screenshot.